# Web Share Api not working on iosv safari as excepted

Tags: webapi, web-share

web share api not working in safari ios 16

here's my function and i want it to works only when clicking a button and pass the parameter i want to share

```
  if (navigator.share) {
    navigator
      .share({
        text: text,
        url: "https://example.com",
        title: "hi",
      })
      .then(() => alert(text))
      .catch((error) => alert("Sharing failed", error));
  } else {
    alert("eror");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61774452/web-share-api-not-working-on-ios-angular?rq=2)? Looks like it could be helpful.

Comment: it didn't works ethir